# Add items to listbox using pushbutton and drop down menu in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I am creating a GUI using GUIDE in MATLAB2015. I have a drop down menu which the user selects a message to view, after that they click the `Add` push button to add the message name to a list box and display the data it contains in a table.

My problem is, if I want to add more than one message, instead of adding that message, it overwrites the previous one. Below is my current code.

```
addData = getappdata(handles.msgSel_menu, 'Data');
boxMsg = get(handles.msgSel_menu,'String');
boxMsgVal = get(handles.msgSel_menu,'Value');
set(handles.activeDataBox,'String',boxMsg{boxMsgVal});
set(handles.data_table, 'Data', addData);
```

Apologies if this has been done multiple times before, but as I'm relatively new to MATLAB I could do with a little explanation of any code that fixes my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to get the initial string cell from your listbox then you add the desired element to the cell. From the resulting cell variable, you update the listbox using the `set` command.

Here is a simple example.

```
addData = getappdata(handles.msgSel_menu, 'Data');
current_data = get(handles.activeDataBox, 'String'); % get the current string
new_data = current_data; % set new_data to the initial string ...
new_data{ length(current_data) + 1 } = addData ; % ... then you add the desired element by incrementing the cell
set(handles.activeDataBox, 'String', new_data); % update your listbox
```

EDIT : The code has been updated.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The problem I'm having with adapting this code is that it keeps throwing an error `Cell contents assignment to a non-cell array object`. Is it something to do with the fact that I'm trying to read the string selected by the user in the drop down menu?

Comment: It seems that your string variable is not a cell. In my code, the data taken from the list box is a cell. In case of a drop down menu, it also should be a cell. You get the string data the same way using the `get` command.

Comment: Ok, this is what I've done by adapting your code. Can you tell me if I've misinterpreted it at all please?

`boxMsg = get(handles.msgSel_menu,'String');
current_data = get(handles.activeDataBox, 'String'); 
boxMsg = current_data; 
new_data = boxMsg{ length(current_data) + 1 }; 
set(handles.activeDataBox, 'String', new_data); % update your listbox`

My listbox is called activeDataBox and my drop down menu is called msgSel_menu.